# poetry and python version errors when upgrading from python 2.7 to 3.7

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, upgrade, python-poetry

I have started a learning effort to teach myself python.  The project started on my mac with python 2.7 as the installed version.  On the advice from a friend, I installed poetry to do dependency handling.  This worked extremely well.

Before long though I realized how out of date python 2.7 was and tried to upgrade.  I did so through homebrew and that seemed to break a lot.  `python --versoin` still shows 2.7 and although I can call `python3 --version` and see the correct my project still seems to be stuck on 2.7 even when `#!/usr/bin/env python3` is at the top of the files.  To make matters worse doing a `poetry up` won't upgrade my python dependency in the project and changing that value in the pyproject.toml brakes everything.  I have a dependency that seems to have broken along the way but can't do anything about it with broken poetry/python version mess. The error is below from the poetry.

So taking this from the top how do I get things to start using the correct version of python?

My bash_profile has

```
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

```
poetry install

[EnvCommandError]                                                                           
Command ['/Users/username/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/PyGameEngine-py2.7/bin/python', '-'] errored with the following return code -6, and output:           
dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../.Python                                                    
  Referenced from: /Users/username/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/PyGameEngine-py2.7/bin/python  
  Reason: image not found                                                                                
input was : import sys                                                                                   
if hasattr(sys, "real_prefix"):                                                                          
    print(sys.real_prefix)                                                                               
elif hasattr(sys, "base_prefix"):                                                                        
    print(sys.base_prefix)                                                                               
else:                                                                                                    
    print(sys.prefix)
```

Comment: So deleting the `/Users/username/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/PyGameEngine-py2.7/bin/python` folder got me to the next error that seems to be the root of my issues ```[RuntimeError]                                                 
The current Python version (2.7.10) is not supported by the project (^3.7)  
Please activate a compatible Python version```

Comment: Try running `poetry install` while inside the virtual env. Do `poetry shell` to activate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying my answer [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60580114/5838056)

---

Interestingly, poetry is silently failing due to a missing package the tool itself relies on and continues to install a broken venv. Here's how you fix it.

```
sudo apt install python3-venv
poetry env remove python3
poetry install
```

I had to remove pytest, and then reinstall with `poetry add pytest`.

EDIT: I ran into this issue again when upgrading a project from python3.7 to python3.8 - for this instead of installing `python3-venv`, you'd want to install `python3.8-venv` instead

---

If you are still having issues ( namely upgrading your packages to be python3 compliant, you may want to take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61415285/5838056) )

Comment: You do know, that he asked about Mac not about Ubuntu?