# How to force reinstall Poetry environment from scratch?

Tags: python-poetry

Poetry has some stale dependencies because the use of `develop = true` packages. Poetry cannot figure out on its own that dependencies have been updated. How do I force Poetry to reinstall everything in its virtualenv to work around this issue?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

These instructions are only for Linux/macOS for Windows Subsystem for Linux. For the Microsoft Windows shell, please use your own command-line knowledge to apply these instructions.

## Recreating Poetry environment

To reinstall the packages for the Poetry environment in the current working directory (UNIX shell):

```bash
# Enter the current Poetry environment
poetry shell

# Remove the current environment
# as referred by path to Python interpreter 
poetry env remove $(which python)

# Reinstall from Poetry's cache
poetry install
```

## Recreating Poetry environment manually

Do the following in the folder with `pyproject.toml`:

```
# Stop the current virtualenv if active or alternative use
# `exit` to exit from a Poetry shell session
deactivate

# Remove all the files of the current environment of the folder we are in
POETRY_LOCATION=`poetry env info -p` 
echo "Poetry is $POETRY_LOCATION"
rm -rf "$POETRY_LOCATION"

# Reactivate Poetry shell
poetry shell

# Install everything
poetry install
```

## Recreating Poetry environment with different Python version

Poetry may refer to your installed Python version, so you might tell it [to change its link to your `python` interpreter as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65589331/315168):

```
# Make Poetry to use python 3.9 from Homebrew, installed earlier
poetry env use `which python3.9`
poetry shell
python -V
```

```
Python 3.9.9
```

[Kudos to this tip about removing the virtualenv](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/926#issuecomment-674552292).

## Fixing damaged poetry command

If the `poetry` command itself is damaged and no longer runs, you can reinstall Poetry by:

```
which poetry
```

```
/Users/mikkoohtamaa/.poetry/bin/poetry
```

Then remove this and [install](https://python-poetry.org/docs/#installation):

```
# macOS
rm -rf /Users/mikkoohtamaa/.poetry
rm -rf  "/Users/$USER/Library/Application Support/pypoetry/venv"


# Linux
rm -rf ~/.local/share/pypoetry/

# Download and run Poetry install script
# If your curl is messed up you can try with --insecure flag
curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org/ | python3 - --force
```

## Extreme painful issues

Sometimes Poetry may just fail to install after you have upgraded your Python e.g. with Homebrew. This might be to do with a fact who Poetry determines which Python version to use.

Errors you can see may include:

```bash
cat /Users/moo/poetry-installer-error-t0zfi7kb.log
```

```
dyld[6526]: Library not loaded: @loader_path/../Python
  Referenced from: <7295E559-55D4-3ACA-9820-D95D1F4AE151> /Users/moo/Library/Application Support/pypoetry/venv/bin/python3.10
  Reason: tried: '/Users/moo/Library/Application Support/pypoetry/venv/bin/../Python' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS@loader_path/../Python' (no such file), '/Users/moo/Library/Application Support/pypoetry/venv/bin/../Python' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/Python' (no such file), '/usr/lib/Python' (no such file, not in dyld cache)

Traceback:

  File "<stdin>", line 923, in main
  File "<stdin>", line 562, in run
```

In this case, recommended approach is to switch away from Homebrew based Pythons and start using [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv):

```bash
brew install pyenv

# Follow the instructions
pyenv init
```

Then in a new shell install a specific Python version and check it is being used:

```bash
pyenv install 3.10
pyenv global 3.10
which python
```

Points to pyenv:

```
/Users/moo/.pyenv/shims/python
```

Now reinstall Poetry using a specific Python version and it should work:

```bash
curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org/ | python3.10 -
```

Comment: The "rm -rf `poetry env info -p` " command will break poetry. Once executed all poetry commands fail with "No pyvenv.cfg file".

Comment: You probably had misinstalled poetry. You can check with `which poetry` command what poetry binary it tries to use.

Comment: `poetry env info -p` yielded nothing for me (it doesn't work outside the activated env), so i used `poetry env list --full-path` and manually copied the path. Thus I recommend splitting `rm -rf \`<something>\`` into 2 steps, or a workaround could be `rm -rf \`poetry run poetry env info -p\``

Comment: Indeed, passing the output of a command to `rm -rf` sounds like a bad advise.

Comment: Beware that when using pyenv poetry env info -p is showing a shim, so that this instruction can broke poetry at all if poetry was installed using this shim. Now I have: "Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding" when running any poetry command

Comment: I believe the command to obtain the path to the environment is now: poetry env info --path

Answer (score 19):

The [official documentation](https://python-poetry.org/docs/managing-environments/#deleting-the-environments) recommends the `poetry env remove` command, which accepts any of the following syntax:

```
poetry env remove /full/path/to/python
poetry env remove python3.11
poetry env remove 3.11
poetry env remove test-O3eWbxRl-py3.11
```

You can remove all virtual environments at once with `poetry env remove --all`

---

As with the accepted answer this will need to be followed by `poetry shell` and `poetry install` to recreate the environment and reinstall dependencies respectively.