# Poetry gives: `TooManyIndirects` error suddenly

Tags: python-poetry

I have a pyproject.toml:

```
...
[[tool.poetry.source]]

name = "REPO_NAME"
url = "https://gitlab.com/SOME_ADDRESS"
secondary = true
```

When trying to install the project using poetry
(`poetry install`/`poetry update`) i get:

> Updating dependencies Resolving dependencies... (14.3s)
>
> TooManyRedirects
>
> Exceeded 30 redirects.

Answer (score 25):

Currently pypi.python.org is [having an issue](https://status.python.org/) and there is nothing one can do about it:

[image]

But hey, it's Friday.

Comment: poetry export --dev > requirements.txt && pip install -r requirements.txt

Comment: The issue seems to be solved. At least my pipeline runs through now, compared to friday.

Answer (score 7):

Clearing the cache seemed to do the trick:

```
poetry cache clear --all REPO_NAME
```

Also, it could happen on global PYPI, in that case run:

```
poetry cache clear --all pypi
```

To list all poetry's repos:

```
poetry cache list
```

Comment: I had the same issue. [See also how to rebuild Poetry installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70064449/how-to-rebuild-poetry-environment-from-scratch-and-force-reinstall-everything/70064450#70064450).

Answer (score 3):

There has been an issue with PyPI Json endpoints that poetry uses. `pip` was unaffected because it uses different endpoints.

A workaround is to export poetry dependencies to the requirements.txt format and use pip:

```
poetry export --dev > requirements.txt && pip install -r requirements.txt
```